# Azure function & Blob Trigger times out

Tags: python, azure, function, cloud

I have some trouble understanding how Function app is working ..

My environment is as follow : Python3.8, Blob Trigger, Cosumption Plan

I am creating an application which is trigger when an audio file is uploaded into a container. This audio file trigger an Azure function and run "Speech-To-Text" using Azure cognitive service (So my function is waiting for an answer from that service). I set up a "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT" at 5 in order to allow each of my function app instance to run several speech-to text analysis in parallel.

**SO I uploaded 100 blob into my container to check my function behaviour, here is what I get :**

Function app is triggered and start several servers (5 for 100 blobs) and then start processing 1 blob per server until it has been more than 30 minutes since I uploaded blob and then I get a Timeout.

**But I was expecting this behaviour :**
Function app is triggered and start several servers. Each servers process 5 blobs in parallel and give me an answer in 15 to 20 minutes for all of my blobs !

So I don't get 2 things here. W

- Why are my functions not processing 5 blobs per server instead of 1 blob per server ? (I set up "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT" at 5) ?
- And my blobs seems to be processed as soon as they appear in the container instead of putting in a queue. And this behaviour is responsible of time out since they are waiting for quite a long time instead of being processed .. WHy ?

I hope I was clear ..
Thank you for your help !

EDIT : I just added 100 blobs to see how function app is reacting, and my freshly uploaded blobs are being processed before the ones that I uploaded at the begining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. For your first question:**

As far as my understanding, [Python is a single-threaded runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#async).

> Because Python is a single-threaded runtime, a host instance for
> Python can process only one function invocation at a time. For
> applications that process a large number of I/O events and/or is I/O
> bound, you can improve performance significantly by running functions
> asynchronously.

And it is right that the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` makes you run 5 blob triggered functions per host, but it would run one by one if you are using the same resource, which means even you could run 5 process at the same time, if the first process is running your function, the second process (run the same function) would waiting; if your first process is waiting for the data come in, the second process would running first.

Here is an article [how `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#use-multiple-language-worker-processes).

And you can check how many worker instances you are using. If you have 100 blobs to trigger your function and 5 worker process set per worker instance, it should starts 20 instances for consuming the request. (Welcome to correct me if I'm wrong.)

---

**2. For your second question:**

> [The Blob storage trigger starts a function when a new or updated blob
> is detected.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp)

That's how blob triggered function works.